# How to load correct theme for each page using localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a website that includes a simple menu (Home, Products, Change Themes, ABout Us). 'Change Theme' is a dropdown menu that has 2 more options ('Default', 'Valentine's).

Change Theme: (Default/Valentines).

When I click one of the options from the 'Change Theme' dropdown menu, for example the "Valentine's" theme, the current page changes to a different theme. Now my homepage(index.html) is loaded with the valentine's theme. When I click a new page from the menu, let's say the "Products" how can I check which CSS stylesheet is currently loaded (current theme) so that I can load the correct theme for the new page. I tried to somehow use the localStorage but since I don't really understand it, it's not working properly.

Because now when I click a page from the menu it loads the default theme (css stylesheet). For each html file I have 2 css files. For example for the index.html I have the 'mainstyle.css' & 'valentines.css'.

Here is some part of the code in the index.html. It's mostly the function and the menu, since the rest of the code is other stuff.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flowers4U</title>

<!-- Link to the external Style Sheet -->
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mainstyle.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Get the selected theme from localStorage or use the default theme
        var selectedTheme = localStorage.getItem('selectedTheme') || 'css/mainstyle.css';

        // Set the stylesheet to the selected theme
        document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', selectedTheme);

        // Function to change the theme
        function change_theme(sheet) {
        // Set the stylesheet to the selected theme
        document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
        // Store the selected theme in localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('selectedTheme', sheet);
        }
    
    </script>

</head>
```

```
<!--Navbar Section-->
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="inner-width">
        <img class="logo" src="img/Logo/logo.png" width="170px" height="60px">

        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="path/aboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a id="mybtn" href="path/index.html">Change Theme ▾</a></li>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#" onclick="change_theme('css/mainstyle.css')">Default</a></li><br></br>
                        <li><a href="#" onclick="change_theme('css/valentines.css')">Valentine's</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="path/products.html">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="path/index.html">Home</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So now when I change the theme on my Home page (index.html) if I refresh it works, but when I open a page from the menu (eg, Products) it uses the mainstyle.css which is the stylesheet for index.html. I entered the same script in the products.html and only changed the css name but I'm guessing I'm using localStorage wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is `onclick="change_theme"` on your change theme dropdown?

Comment: Didn't realise I didn't remove it after adding the 2 options. I removed it now

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my issue. I don't know if it's the most efficient way but I simply added an if statement in the script that check which stylesheet from the previous pages is used and then loads the correct one for the current page.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            // Get the selected theme from localStorage or use the default theme
            var selectedTheme = localStorage.getItem('selectedTheme') || 'css/mainstyle.css';

            //Load the correct theme
            if ((localStorage.getItem('selectedTheme') == 'css/products.css') || (localStorage.getItem('selectedTheme') == 'css/aboutUs.css'))
            {
                var selectedTheme = 'css/mainstyle.css';
            }
            else if ((localStorage.getItem('selectedTheme') == 'css/v_products.css') || (localStorage.getItem('selectedTheme') == 'css/v_aboutUs.css'))
            {
                var selectedTheme = 'css/valentines.css';
            }

            // Set the stylesheet to the selected theme
            document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', selectedTheme);

            // Function to change the theme
            function change_theme(sheet) {
            // Set the stylesheet to the selected theme
            document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
            // Store the selected theme in localStorage
            localStorage.setItem('selectedTheme', sheet);
            }
        
        </script>
```